# How to save only after characters are typed in a note app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm new to android development. Literally a few days in and I built a simple note taking app. I would like for the notes to only save after I type something. So if my layout is empty I don't want it to save after I press the back button.

My current code is below. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    saveAndFinish();
}
```

Comment: When you press the back button, you verify if the layout is empty. If it isn't, you save the content. What's the problem?

Comment: Java != javascript ;) I removed the tag but wanted to make sure you understood that

Comment: I'd suggest you to save anything in onPause() instead of onBackPressed(), because the user can leave your app by pressing home, and your onBackPressed won't be called.

Comment: Good call. I just added that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is something typed in:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
    if (et.length() > 0) {
        saveAndFinish();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

As a note, you might want to check if `!et.getText().toString().trim().equals("")` just to make sure that it will not save whitespace.

Comment: @mike_yaworski I've been attempting to add that same line of code to the menu, but to no avail.

Comment: To the menu... hmmm go to http://pastie.org and paste your code for that and I'll take a look. Send me the link.

Comment: @mike_yaworski Thank you very much - [http://pastie.org/private/lutbnpqtvolcl1bogslevq#1-8]

Comment: @mike_yaworski Hmmmm the code works only if you type in text, not when it's blank. So it's still not allowing me to exit that note.

Comment: @MinimalCode So you type text in, and then press the menu home option and it saves and finishes. But if the text is blank and you press the menu home option, nothing happens?

Comment: @mike_yaworski exactly.

Comment: @MinimalCode Well of course. You say "if it's *not* blank, save and finish" but you never handle the condition for when it *is* blank. Check out this pastie: http://pastie.org/private/wzpcd9a17xto5p5eiw7b1q

Comment: @mike_yaworski I added "finish();" to simply return to the previous page if empty. Thank you very much for all of the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (! layout.isEmpty() ) { 
        saveAndFinish();
    }
}
```

I made up this method `layout.isEmpty()`. Change
`layout.isEmpty()` with the appropriate check.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if there is any value. Assuming you have one `EditText` that the user types in

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    if (!myEditText.getText.toString().equals(""))
    {    saveAndFinish();  }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```